# BubbleNode.getDefaultGeometry missing from Autodesk Forge Viewer TypeScript Bindings

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Like the title says, the getDefaultGeometry method is missing on the BubbleNode class in the Autodesk Forge Viewer typescript bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being addressed here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/41577

Apologies for the delay - had too much on my plate

Answer (score 0):

@Bryan, Actually, this update still doesn't solve the problem. BubbleNode type's getDefaultGeometry doesn't take (searchMasterViews) input parameter.

```
class BubbleNode {
    ...
    getDefaultGeometry(): any;
```

Without that, I can't load Floors/Rooms from AEC data.

For now, I created a type-overload in my code and got it working, but please correct it for the benefit of the others.

```
interface IBubbleNode {
    getDefaultGeometry: (searchMasterViews: boolean) => Autodesk.Viewing.BubbleNode
}
```

If there is a better way to do this, please suggest.
Thank you 
Bandu